# Question about Hankel's contour applied for Gamma functions

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

I would like to have some explanation (or pehaps some intuition) on the Hankel's contour for the following contour integral:  $$ F(n)= \oint_{C} \frac{e^{ -z} }{z^{n+1}} \,dz$$

,where n is non-integer.

Arfken's textbook shows how this end up relating to the gamma function, which it is not what I am asking here.  Also I understand that the cut is chosen to be on the positive real axis for convergence of the integrand.

My question/confusion is that we usually try to avoid enclosing a branch cut while evaluating complex integrals (Hankel's contour being an exception), but on the picture below, we end up including the branch cuts and branch points and never closing the contour (I also understand this has a residue at infinity for n non-integer):

[image]

If I could get explanation on why I am allowed to include branch cuts (counterclockwise direction instead of excluding them) and why not closing the contour (I am assuming it is because the branch cut goes to infinity and there is a residue at infinity, but I am not sure), it would be nice.

Comment: It definitely wouldn't hurt if you had told us what your contour C is in the original contour integral and what branch of the denominator you are using. Without that it all looks quite mysterious, indeed.

Comment: @fedja : I already placed a picture of the contour (green and blue lines in the counter clockwise direction) and the formulation of the contour as the textbook presented. The branch of the denominator used there was from 0 to infinity (red line) and n non integer. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are asking: I can draw any path between finite points or escaping to infinity in the domain of analyticity and ask to compute the integral along this path. And so could Hankel. Of course, the question remains why any of us should do it, but I presume your textbook uses this contour to compute some interesting integrals or to derive some non-trivial representation of functions and not just for its own sake.

Comment: @fedja : I did not get why using an open contour instead of a closed one (in this case it is not enclosing the branch or any residues). My mistake is that I would think anything to left of my contour had to be accounted for (including the branch cut or residues). But this is only true for closed contours, correct? Second:I was not sure is why using clockwise versus counter clockwise. My take is that the sign in clockwise contour will make result to be the same with a negative sign,so I am not so sure what determines the orientation (maybe 
 integral in polar coordinates will determine that?).