# Why is a Hankel Contour a closed loop?

Tags: complex-analysis

As far as I know, $[0, \infty)$ isn't a closed set, so how does Cauchy's integral theorem apply in order to use the residue theorem on a Hankel contour when extending a real integral?

Comment: Either one can close the contour by a big circle (which will not contribute) or when this is not possible, one can usually show that the contour can still be deformed without changing the integral, and in this case, the limit (on the parameter that describe the deformation of the contour) exists. cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3750925/92038)